# Could not find method cargo() for arguments

Tags: gradle, cargo

I am trying to deploy war to tomcat with gradle cargo,i am getting error could not found method cargo()

> C:\Users\naresh.vatsal\workspace_spring_jan14\SpringMvcUsingGradle>gradle build
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>   Build file 'C:\Users\naresh.vatsal\workspace_spring_jan14\SpringMvcUsingGradle\build.gradle' line: 45
>
> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SpringMvcUsingGradle'.
>
> Could not find method cargo() for arguments [build_3gitu3al50b7kv8zi1ebj3qsr$runclosure3@302aa00f] on root project 'SpringMvcUsingGradle'.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat-base'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo-base'
ext.tomcatVersion = '7.0.67'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.grdev.net/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.4"
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    def cargoVersion = '1.4.5'
    cargo "org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-uberjar:$cargoVersion",
          "org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-ant:$cargoVersion"
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.15'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.7'
}

cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat7x'
    port = 8080

    local {
        homeDir = file('C:/mdi/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67')
        output = file('C:/mdi/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/output.log')
    }
}

war { 
    version = '' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you've applied the wrong plugin at the moment. Just change:

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo-base'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'
```

Because, when you apply the `com.bmuschko.cargo-base` plugin, you have to configure each task individually, according to the [plugin description](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin).

And one more, there is no property `output`, which could be defined within the `local` closure, but there is an `outputFile` property, so, your `local` closure should look like:

```
local {
    homeDir = file('C:/mdi/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67')
    outputFile = file('C:/mdi/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/output.log')
}
```